# No puedo ver elementos del layout

Tags: android, android-studio

LLevo todo el dia intentando que se muestre un simple elemento como un TextView en el movil o en la maquina virtual. No entiendo porque se muestra en blanco el elemento. La  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Jose, Debes ser un poco mas especifico con tu respuesta, tu error puede ser muchos factores y lo mas probable es que terminen cerrando la pregunta por reportes de baja calidad, ¿podrías dar mas detalles de tu problema?

Comment: Lo siento, pero es así de simple. Hago en el editor de layouts un RelativeLayout o un LinearLayout o un ConstraintLayout y le añado un Button o un TextView. Me dispongo a probarlo en el movil y no se ve nada, en la avd igual. Todo en blanco. Lamento explicarme de manera tan nefasta ayer.

Comment: Me equivoqué en el método onCreate. Tras toda la mañana haciendo pruebas. Me he percatado de que no cargaba ni el layout, tampoco un simple comentario en un Log. He cambiado el método y ahora anda perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu layout se llama `josel.xml`, si deseas ver este layout, verifica tu `Activity`, asegura que sea el que se cargue mediante el método `setContentView()`

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.josel);
        ...
        ...
        ...         
    }
```